# Having trouble executing a function from another Python file

Tags: python, list, function, append

So im writing a simple program to calculate volume for a cube based on user input. I have a main.py and a volume.py. In the main.py, I simply call the respective function cubeVolume. However when I try to append the resulting cube volume from volume.py into a list in main.py called cubeList, I get an undefined error. How can I fix this?

```
#main.py
from volume import cubeVolume
import math

cubeList = []
userInput = str(input("Enter the shape you wish to calculate the volume for: "))
userInput = ''.join(userInput.split()).lower().capitalize()

while userInput != "Q" or userInput != "Quit":
    if userInput == "C" or userInput == "Cube":
        cubeSide = int(input("Enter the side length for the Cube: "))
        cubeVolume(cubeSide)
        cubeList.append(volume)
```

Here is the volume.py file

```
#volume.py
import math

def cubeVolume(side):
    volume = side**3
    print("The volume of the cube with side length {} is: {}".format(side, volume))
```

**Heres my output:**

```
Enter the shape you wish to calculate the volume for: cube
Enter the side length for the Cube: 3
    The volume of the cube with side length 3 is: 27
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/User/Desktop/folder2/main.py", line 14, in <module>
        cubeList.append(volume)
    NameError: name 'volume' is not defined
```

Comment: you need to define a `return` at the end of your cubeVolume function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`volume` is a local variable to the `cubeVolume` function and is inaccessible outside of it. You should make your `cubeVolume` return `volume` so that the main program can have access its value:

```
def cubeVolume(side):
    volume = side**3
    print("The volume of the cube with side length {} is: {}".format(side, volume))
    return volume
```

And in the main program, change:

```
cubeVolume(cubeSide)
cubeList.append(volume)
```

to:

```
cubeList.append(cubeVolume(cubeSide))
```

Comment: Also add the fact that the `while` loop exit condition is not being met

Comment: @CosmicCat Again, this is because `volume` is defined as a local variable in the `cubeVolume` function. Callers to this function have no access to its local variables, and the proper way that a caller can get a value from a function is through its returning value.

Comment: just one more quick question... ive been trying to use the round(volume, 2) function to round the 'volume' variable right after I declared it and before the print statement but it does not work for some reason. any thoughts